# Source activation for anaconda python environments no longer working (Mac)

Tags: macos, anaconda

The source activate command in conda is suddenly no longer working for me. When I type `source activate py3` in my Mac terminal, I get this error `-bash: _conda_activate: command not found`.

I recently created a new conda environment for TabPy (Tableau python server); I'm not sure if that changed anything. I have checked that the conda environments I'm trying to activate exist by using `conda info --envs`, here is that output:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/applemacbook/anaconda
Tableau-Python-Server     /Users/applemacbook/anaconda/envs/Tableau-Python 
Server
py3                      /Users/applemacbook/anaconda/envs/py3
```

I already have the following in my bash profile from my initial installation of anaconda awhile ago `export PATH="/Users/applemacbook/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`.

Based on some comments from related threads, here is some additional information:
The output of `which conda` is `/Users/applemacbook/anaconda/bin/conda`.
The output of `type source` is `source is a shell builtin`.
The output of `which activate` is `/Users/applemacbook/anaconda/bin/activate`.

Comment: What is the version of conda?

Comment: @darthbith My conda version is conda 4.4.6

Comment: Definitely a bug.  Please file an issue at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues